# Make Webpack dynamic import reuse a bundled module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have separate components for logged in vs logged out people, i.e.:

```
const AuthRoute = React.lazy(async () => import('routes/AuthRoute'));

const UnauthRoute = React.lazy(async () => import('routes/UnauthRoute'));

export default function HomeRoute() {
  return useAuth() ? <AuthRoute /> : <UnauthRoute />
}
```

Then, I created separate bundles for auth and unauth, i.e. `auth.js`:

```
import './main.ts'; // initialize everything
import 'routes/AuthRoute';
```

Then I load `auth.js` or `unauth.js` based on whether localstorage auth tokens are set. If the auth tokens are invalid, it'll load `auth.js`, then make another request to fetch `UnauthRoute`. If the auth tokens are valid, I expect it to not need to fetch `AuthRoute` since it's already in the bundle, but it's still fetching that file.

Is it possible to configure Webpack to reuse the bundled `AuthRoute` instead of making another network request when calling `import('routes/AuthRoute')`?